# Position of Place holders like {0} changing in Arabic text

Tags: c#, windows-ce, string.format, arabic-support

In C# 3.9 with WinCE OS, I face issue in parsing Place holders like {0} OR {1} which are part of input Arabic text. For example, {0} should be replaced by some value at runtime-

يرجى إعادة معالجة {0} العملات الورقية التي تم استبعادها

This is the code written.

```
 string text = يرجى إعادة معالجة {0} العملات الورقية التي تم استبعادها
 string title = string.Format(value, "Market");
```

The {0} should be replaced by "Market". However with Arabic , the "Market" is getting positioned to another index, like below, WHICH IS WRONG-

```
يرجى إعادة معالMarketجة  العملات الورقية التي تم استبعادها
```

Please advise  a way out. Everything works well with other languages having LTR direction

Comment: While duplicate picked by @mjwills shows what you *may need to do* the question would be much more reasonable if it contained actually compliable code and in this particular case *images* of what you get and what you expect. In general there is relatively small number of people who can look at such text and say what is "correct" and what is not as RTL/LTR mixed text have hard to understand (for non native reader of RTL text) rules.  Additionally browsers (as shown in the question) may render such text differently and especially if you are asking about such rare platform as WinCE.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok, thanks for info, shall add images, as my question remains unanswered